# In the proof of showing $\operatorname{Ad}_{*} =\operatorname{ad} $ (adjoint representations of Lie Group(Algebra).

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'am reading the Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds, 2nd edition, p.534, Theorem 20.27 and stuck at understanding some equality :

[image]

**Why the underlined equality is true?** Here, $\operatorname{ad} : \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{gl(g)}$ is the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\operatorname{Ad}_{*} :\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{gl(g)}$ is the induced Lie algebra representation which is defined as follows (His book p.195) :

[image]

Here, the 'L' in the above underlined definition of $Y$ is defined as follows (His book, p.191) : Let $G$ be a Lie group. Let $v\in T_{e}G$ be arbitrary. Then define a (left invariant) vector field $v^{L}$ on $G$ by

$$ v^{L}|_g = d(L_g)_{e}(v)$$.

**Note that** by the proof of his book, Theorem 8.37 (p.191), the correspondence $L$ is an isomorphism $T_eG \to \operatorname{Lie}(G) =: \mathfrak{g}$ with inverse $\epsilon : \operatorname{Lie}(G) \to T_eG$, given by $\epsilon(X) := X_e$.

It seems that our question is somewhat basic but I don't know how to establish the equality rigorously. What should I notice?

**First attempt** : Let $H:=GL(\mathfrak{g})$ and let $\mathfrak{h}:=\mathfrak{gl(g)}$ be its Lie algebra. Let $\gamma : t \mapsto \operatorname{exp}tX$.

Then
$$\frac{d} {dt} |_{t=0} (\operatorname{Ad}(\operatorname{exp}tX)) 
= (\operatorname{Ad} \circ \gamma)^{'}(0) = d(\operatorname{Ad})_{\gamma(0)}(\gamma^{'}(0)) = d(\operatorname{Ad})_{e}(X_e) \in T_eH$$.

And,
$$\operatorname{Ad}_{*}(X) = (d(\operatorname{Ad})_{e}(X_e))^{L} \in \operatorname{Lie}H =: \mathfrak{h} = \mathfrak{gl(g)} $$

And why the difference appear?
I think that for the first equality, more correct form is,

$$(\operatorname{Ad}_{*}X)Y = (\frac{d} {dt} |_{t=0} (\operatorname{Ad}(\operatorname{exp}tX)))^{L}(Y) $$

Did I make point out well?

If so, it remains(the second equality) to show that

$$(\frac{d} {dt} |_{t=0} (\operatorname{Ad}(\operatorname{exp}tX)))^{L}(Y) = \frac{d} {dt} |_{t=0}(\operatorname{Ad}(\operatorname{exp}tX)Y) $$

How can we show this? How the passage of $Y$ into the derivative $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}$  ( ; i.e., the second equality) possible? If we can use the Chain rule, how can we apply the chain rule more rigorously?

Can anyone helps?

Comment: The first equals sign is basically the definition of the induced homomorphism and the second is just chain rule.

Comment: My question is, "the 'L' really apears in the $\operatorname{Ad}_{*}(X)$, as formula above? If so, on the other side, why L doesn't apears in for formula for $\frac{d} {dt} |_{t=0} \operatorname{Ad}(\operatorname{exp}tX))$." And for the second equality, what chain rule you mentioned exactly means? I know a version of chain rule for multivariable calculus. And in our case, what does it means? Where can I find assoicated data/reference?

Comment: So for the first point $X$ and $X^L$ are being identified here.

Comment: @Callum : Can you explain how to apply the Chain rule?

Answer (score 2):

Here are my thoughts, which are too long to write down in the comment section. I believe what follows is substantially correct, with "holes"perhaps. I would appreciate any corrections/feedback.

Ad maps $G$ into $h=GL(\frak g)$ so Ad$_*$ maps $\frak g$ into $\frak h$ which is just $GL(\frak g)$ itself with the Lie bracket, and is written $\frak gl(g).$

Now, $X\in \frak g$ is identified with $X_e$ because of the $X\to X_e$ isomorphism of $\frak g$ with $T_eG.$ Similarly, Ad$_*X$ as an element of $\frak gl(g)$ is identified with an element of the tangent space at the identity in the tangent bundle of $\frak gl(g),$ which is just an element of $\frak gl(g)$ itself because the latter is a vector space. And so the formula Ad$_*X(Y)$ makes sense.

We also know that $X$ is a left-invariant vector field on $M$ so there is a one-parameter subgroup $\gamma$ which satisfies $X_{\gamma(t)}=\gamma'(t).$ And of course, $\gamma(t)=\exp tX.$

So, by definition of the pushforward, with which the induced Lie algebra representation is identified (I have not verified the validity of the identification), and with test function $f$, we get

Ad$_*X_ef=$Ad$_*X_{\gamma(0)}f=$Ad$_*\gamma'(0)f=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}f($Ad$\circ \gamma(t))=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}f($Ad$(\exp tX)).$

Hence, the first equality in the formula is correct.

Edit: here is a more careful proof:

$c^g:G\to G$ is defined by $c^g(x)=g^{-1}xg.$ Henceforth, we simply write this as $c.$

$\operatorname{Ad}:G\to \operatorname{GL}(\frak g)$ is defined by $\operatorname{Ad}(g)=c_*:\frak g \to \frak g,$ the induced Lie Algebra homomorphism.

$\operatorname{ad}:\frak g\to \operatorname{Hom}(\frak g, \frak g)=\frak gl(g)$ is defined by $\operatorname{ad}(X)=\operatorname{Ad_*}(X).$

$\operatorname{Hom}(\frak g, \frak g)$ is the Lie algebra of the Lie group $\operatorname{GL}(\frak g)$ in the same way as the Lie algebra $gl_n(\mathbb{C})$ of the general linear group $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ can be identified with the space $M_n(\mathbb C)$ of $n×n$ complex matrices, with the Lie bracket $[A,B]=AB−BA$.

The key  identification is in what follows. By definition,

$\operatorname{Ad_*}(X)=(d\operatorname{Ad}_e(X_e))^L: \frak g\to \frak gl(g)$

which is the same as

$d\operatorname{Ad}_e(X):T_eG\to T_I(\operatorname{GL}(\frak g)).$

Hence,

$\operatorname{Ad_*}(X)=d\operatorname{Ad}_e(X)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\operatorname{Ad}(\exp tX)dt.$

For the second part, it's just a matter of unwinding the definitions:

Fix $X\in \frak g.$ We have $\operatorname{Ad}\exp 0X=\operatorname{Ad}e=I$ (because $\operatorname{Ad}$ is a homomorphism.) Write $F:=\operatorname{Ad}\exp,$ take a $Y\in \frak g$ and compute, at $t=0$, the difference quotient:

$\tag1 \left(n\left(\left(F(t+\frac{1}{n}\right)X-I\right)\right)Y=n\left(\left(F(t+\frac{1}{n}\right)X)(Y)-Y\right).$

Now, define $F(tX)=\tilde F_X(t)$ and notice that $\tilde F_X(t)\in \operatorname{GL}(\frak g).$ Using these facts, rewrite $(1):$

$\tag2 n\left(\tilde F_X\left(t+\frac{1}{n}\right)-I\right)Y=n\left(\tilde F_X\left(t+\frac{1}{n}\right)Y-Y\right).$

The limit on the left-hand side is

$\tag3 \left(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\tilde F_X(t)\right)Y=\left(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\operatorname{Ad}\exp tX\right)Y$

so the limit on the right-hand side exists and is equal to it. Now notice that $\tilde F_X(0)Y=Y$ so the limit on the right-hand side of $(2)$ is

$\tag4 \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\tilde F_X(t)Y=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\left(\operatorname{Ad}\exp X\right)Y$

Comment: O.K. Thank you. For the first equality, I've edited my question after some thought. Can you see? And For the second equality : in your answer, what is $h$? And how can we apply your comment to our situation? In our situation, what will be $F$, $G$, and $L$?

Comment: C.f. Precisely, symbols $(\operatorname{Ad}(\operatorname{exp}tX))_e$ and $\operatorname{Ad}(\operatorname{exp}tX)^{L}|_g$ are nonsense. :) Because $\operatorname{Ad}(\operatorname{exp}tX)$ is neither included in $\mathfrak{g}$ nor $T_eG$.

Comment: O.K. For the second part, regarding the chain rule, I think it needs some more thought. A priori, it seems possible ( since $Y$ does not depends on $t$) but I couldn't make a formal proof. Now I am trying to apply the Loring Tu's p.88's version of Chain rule (Theorem 8.5). Can we apply the theorem successfully ? If so, how?

Comment: I have added a more careful proof to my answer. I will delete all my previous comments.

Comment: O.K. I think I should point out few things. First, you defined $\operatorname{ad}$ as $\operatorname{Ad}_{*}$. But in john lee's book, $\operatorname{ad}$ is defined differently, and $\operatorname{ad} = \operatorname{Ad}_{*}$ is objective/goal of the his book Theorem 20.27, not a definition. Second,  following his book (e.g. Theorem 8.44 as above image), $\operatorname{Ad}_{*}(X)$ is an element of $\mathfrak{gl}(\mathfrak{g})$. I don' know how can you view $\operatorname{Ad}_{*}(X)$ as $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{gl}(\mathfrak{g})$.

Comment: Third, similarly, $d \operatorname{Ad}_e(X_e)$ is an element of $T_I(GL(\mathfrak{g}))$. Also, I don't know how can you regard $d \operatorname{Ad}_e(X_e)$ as $T_eG \to T_I(GL(\mathfrak{g}))$.~~

Comment: Yes. the proof of $\operatorname{ad} = \operatorname{Ad}_{*}$ from the definition of $\operatorname{ad}$ as the Lie bracket is the Theorem 20.27. I've read his full proof. And for the 'second identification', you mean $\mathfrak{g} \cong T_eG$ and $\mathfrak{gl}(\mathfrak{g}) \cong T_I(GL(\mathfrak{g}))$? My question is, possibility of regarding $\operatorname{Ad}_{*}(X)$ (element of $\mathfrak{gl}(g)$) as a map $\mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{gl}(g)$ ! Please understand If there is something I didn't catch ~

Comment: Anyway, and, I think that application of the chain rule remains completely unsolved problem :)

Comment: I rewrote the second part, without appealing to the chain rule.

Comment: Thanks, Can I ask question?  Why the limit on the left side of (2) leads to (3)? And similarly, why the limit on the right side of (3) leads to (4)? How can we take the limit? (Why you introduce the notation $n$ in the limit argument?) Can you explain more kindly?~